# Delphi 2010: integrated code formatter disappeared from menu

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, code-formatting

How to get back integrated source code formatting back to Delphi? I suppose I disabled some package or something and there is no more an option in Edit menu to format source. What package should I get back installed to have it on again?

Comment: If you found out what happened be sure tell it to all the people who want to **get rid** of the formatter. ;-)

Comment: @Ulrich: If you install DDevExtensions and check the option to disable the formatter's shortcut, that doesn't get rid of the formatter as such, but it does get rid of its intrusiveness.

Comment: To get rid of it just delete Embarcadero.Modeling.Formatter.dll in bin folder of installation. But it presents in mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install Modeling - to have code formatter
Uninstall Modeling - to remove it

Answer (score 1):

See question [How to disable the Formatter in Delphi 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738838/how-to-disable-the-formatter-in-delphi-2010). More specifically [How to disable the Formatter in Delphi 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738838/how-to-disable-the-formatter-in-delphi-2010/1738866#1738866) and re-install the dll mentioned in that answer