# Automatic Code Formatting in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am amazed by the automatic code formatting feature in VB.Net IDE that when you type a line of code and then move the cursor off that line, the code will automatically be indented and the proper text type cases will be applied as if the code was formatted with the coding standards. Is there any IDE experts, IDE plugins etc that will make Delphi IDE do the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) has a [code formatter](http://www.dummzeuch.de/delphi/gexperts/english.html). Also, Delphi 2010 has it out-of-the-box.

The difference with the VB.Net IDE is that in Delphi you can actually choose if you want to use this or not...

Comment: The formatter isn't included in Gexperts, but there is an "experimental" version with formatting included.  It requires some manual installation.

Comment: A, I didn't even remember that! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

Please, see this thread:
[Delphi code formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402737/delphi-code-formatter)

I have discussed this question. You can find various sugestion for this question/problem.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The [Experimental Builds of GExperts](http://www.dummzeuch.de/delphi/gexperts/english.html) contain a formatter that is based on the Dutch [DelForExp](http://www.aew.wur.nl/UK/Delforexp/).

It is way better than the code formatter included in Delphi 2010 ([some people even disable that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738838/how-to-disable-the-formatter-in-delphi-2010)), but has some drawbacks too:
it does not support generics, and has problems with other modern constructs like class vars and such.

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 2010 have buid in but need a click but unfortunately, Embarcadero does not use it on their own delphi codes hence bugs and short options

Cheers